# What databases have both iOS and Android clients and can work offline?

Tags: android, database, ios, offline

Is there any database that:

- has iOS and Android clients to do basic operations (CRUD)
- open fast
- synchronizes to one central source
- doesn't require internet to work (the operations can be sent later)
- is free (optional)

Airtable doesn't satisfy the 4th requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) and/or [rqlite](https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite)

> SQLite is a C-language library that implements a small, fast, self-contained, high-reliability, full-featured, SQL database engine.

> rqlite is an easy-to-use, lightweight, distributed relational database, which uses SQLite as its storage engine.

or any project that provides some sort of replication for sqlite Files.
Perhaps ask at the sqlite User forum if my suggestion is really feasible.

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker can do that.

- You can install it on [iOS and Linux](https://www.claris.com/resources/downloads/).
- no, it's not free

**EDIT:**

If it's important for you to have an Android client you can use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tonocodelabs.dbclient&hl=en&gl=US&pli=1) but it's only compatible with MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: where in the link does it say about iOS and Android clients? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: IOS and Linux. I don't think there are Android clients in general for databases

Comment: but where does in the link say that? And why are there no Android clients for databases?

Comment: I never heard about a database client for Android. Have you?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I ask this question. But I would be surprised if no-one does that. That seems trivial

Comment: No, there are zero software that do that.

Comment: but what makes you be sure about that? And isn't that the new edit contradicts to that?\

Comment: I added an edit because that is the only thing I found on internet. I never tested that.